# Magento2 : Show category name on product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento-2.0

I need to show category name on product detail page just before product name.

Currently product name display as page title but i need to display additionally product name with class new class name. category name will also display with class name just before product name.

How i can complete the task.

Comment: What is class name?

Comment: class name which is append to html.

Comment: This is the default html `<h1 class="page-title"><span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">[product-name]</span></h1>`. How your html have to be?

Comment: i need to show category name. how can it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to display category name in product detail page.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentcategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
echo $currentcategory->getName();
```